# Application Insight Snapshot Debugger: Snapshots are not being pushed from a .NET Full Framework Site

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I created a brand new Web Application, .NET Full Framework 4.7.2, added Application Insights Snapshot Collector but snapshots are not being pushed to the server.

I'm not even getting the `Don't see the snapshot? troubleshoot` link they mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger-troubleshoot).

I tested my integration key using a .NET Core app and it works as expected, and I'm even getting logs at `%TEMP%\Dumps64` as they mention in that document.

I don't see any activity in the %TEMP% folder when I use the .NET Framework app. Exceptions are being pushed to Application Insights, so the integration key is valid and the exceptions are being trapped.

These are the packages I added:

```cs
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector" version="1.3.3" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net472" />
```

And this is how my `ApplicationInsights.config` looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>[MY INTEGRATION KEY IS HERE]</InstrumentationKey>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <!-- Extended list of bots:
            search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|BrowserMob|BingPreview|PagePeeker|WebThumb|URL2PNG|ZooShot|GomezA|Google SketchUp|Read Later|KTXN|KHTE|Keynote|Pingdom|AlwaysOn|zao|borg|oegp|silk|Xenu|zeal|NING|htdig|lycos|slurp|teoma|voila|yahoo|Sogou|CiBra|Nutch|Java|JNLP|Daumoa|Genieo|ichiro|larbin|pompos|Scrapy|snappy|speedy|vortex|favicon|indexer|Riddler|scooter|scraper|scrubby|WhatWeb|WinHTTP|voyager|archiver|Icarus6j|mogimogi|Netvibes|altavista|charlotte|findlinks|Retreiver|TLSProber|WordPress|wsr-agent|http client|Python-urllib|AppEngine-Google|semanticdiscovery|facebookexternalhit|web/snippet|Google-HTTP-Java-Client-->
      <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
  -->
  <TelemetrySinks>
    <Add Name="default">
      <TelemetryProcessors>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector">
          <!-- The default is true, but you can disable Snapshot Debugging by setting it to false -->
          <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
          <!-- Snapshot Debugging is usually disabled in developer mode, but you can enable it by setting this to true. -->
          <!-- DeveloperMode is a property on the active TelemetryChannel. -->
          <IsEnabledInDeveloperMode>true</IsEnabledInDeveloperMode>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
        </Add>
      </TelemetryProcessors>
      <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
    </Add>
  </TelemetrySinks>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
      <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
        <!-- 
        Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers.         
        Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
        NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
        <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
        <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
        <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
      </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
      <IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
        <Add>Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs</Add>
        <Add>Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus</Add>
      </IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
      <!--
      Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:

      <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
        ...
      </Counters>

      PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

      NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.

      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
      -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
      <!--
      Remove individual fields collected here by adding them to the ApplicationInsighs.HeartbeatProvider 
      with the following syntax:

      <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights">
        <ExcludedHeartbeatProperties>
          <Add>osType</Add>
          <Add>location</Add>
          <Add>name</Add>
          <Add>offer</Add>
          <Add>platformFaultDomain</Add>
          <Add>platformUpdateDomain</Add>
          <Add>publisher</Add>
          <Add>sku</Add>
          <Add>version</Add>
          <Add>vmId</Add>
          <Add>vmSize</Add>
          <Add>subscriptionId</Add>
          <Add>resourceGroupName</Add>
          <Add>placementGroupId</Add>
          <Add>tags</Add>
          <Add>vmScaleSetName</Add>
        </ExcludedHeartbeatProperties>
      </Add>

      NOTE: exclusions will be lost upon upgrade.
      -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
      <!--</Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.FirstChanceExceptionStatisticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">-->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Handlers>
        <!-- 
        Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 

        NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
      </Handlers>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  </TelemetryModules>
  <ApplicationIdProvider Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>

<!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
  -->
    <TelemetryProcessors>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector">
            <!-- Snapshot Debugging is usually disabled when debugging in Visual Studio, but you can enable it by setting this to true. -->
            <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
            <!-- Snapshot Debugging is usually disabled in developer mode, but you can enable it by setting this to true. -->
            <!-- DeveloperMode is a property on the active TelemetryChannel. -->
            <IsEnabledInDeveloperMode>true</IsEnabledInDeveloperMode>
            <!-- How many times we need to see an exception before we ask for snapshots. -->
            <ThresholdForSnapshotting>1</ThresholdForSnapshotting>
            <!-- Other properties are documented at https://aka.ms/pnv0qt -->
        </Add>
    </TelemetryProcessors>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Answered this originally in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1353).

So I've just spent almost a day trying to make snapshot debugger work in a legacy ASP.NET application and now it finally works!
While there's no guarantee that the issue I've encountered is the same as yours was, I believe it is quite possible, because the symptoms I experienced were basically the same.

**TL;DR**: it is `<assemblyBinding>`.

#### Problem

Application Insights probably tries to be resilient to failures by preferring to (silently?) ignore them.

And that is what it does to `SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor`. It simply silently skips it if it fails to load and proceeds happily without it.
You can verify this by entering any garbage instead of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector`
as `Type` attribute value in `ApplicationInsights.config`.

And if you check `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessors`, it will simply miss those it failed to load.

A sure way to verify that problem is with assembly loading, just add this line somewhere in startup code:

```cs
var _ = typeof(SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor);
```

That should trigger the error.

AFAIK, unlike with class library projects, `Web.config` in ASP.NET applications cannot benefit from `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>`, while NuGet package manager in VS won't do it either once you move to `PackageReference` (or to "new csproj with globs" like I did). So you have to maintain it somewhat manually.

#### "Fix"

As of today, assuming you have these reference versions in your `csproj` file,

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector" Version="1.3.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" Version="2.14.0" />
```

you will probably need at least these redirects in Web.config

```xml
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.14.0.17971" newVersion="2.14.0.17971" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.7.0" newVersion="1.3.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

After adding those, I could see the `SnapshotUploader` directory created on disk and soon after simulating exceptions, some snapshots in the portal.

#### Extra quirks

As described above, the configuration by default is wrongly added to the root in `ApplicationInsights.config` and not under default sink.

Additionally, that sink configuration created by `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` contains duplicate entries for `AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor`, which will probably cause much less telemetry to be sampled than expected in some cases.

Comment: did your snapshot shows local vars? In my case the snapshot uploaded, but local vars always empty. Would you mind to check my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244075/appinsight-snapshot-debbugger-doesnt-show-locals-vars